# How to fake nested use of third-party APIs involving potentially dangerous actions?

Tags: clojure, automated-tests

I have three services in a Clojure application:

- `Service A`:  interacts with a third-party API, causing potentially dangerous and irreversible changes within the external service (may not be written by me)
- `Service B`:  consumes Service A to accomplish its goals
- `Service C`:  consumes Service B to accomplish its own goals

I need to write integration tests for Service C that *do not* call out to the third-party, as they provide neither a set of testing endpoints nor a way to reverse my changes.

The two options I see are:

- Pass called functions into Service C, like how one would inject service instances in an OOP language.  This causes a lot of additional overhead when actually using Service C.
- Mocking the dangerous functions in Service A using `with-redefs-fn`.  This requires knowing implementation details of services that I may not control.

I am somewhat new to testing in functional languages, so it's more than possible that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you know *some* details about the implementation of the services, and those are mostly written in Java, you can use `proxy` to create an alternate implementations of the classes or interfaces that you want to constraint during the tests.

An example would look like:

```
(let [proxy-a (proxy [com.dangerous.ServiceA] []
                (launchMissiles [x y z]
                  (log/info "Phew! we didn't fire a missile during tests!")))

      proxy-b  (proxy [com.example.ServiceB] []
                 (callServiceA [x y z]
                   (.launchMissiles proxy-a x y z)))

      proxy-c (proxy [com.example.ServiceC] [x]
                (callServiceB [x]
                 (.callServiceB proxy-b x 1 2)))]

     ;; Perform a test on the outer proxy with:
     (.callServiceB proxy-c "testing!")
```

More details here: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy

Comment: While this is unfortunately not something I could guarantee, it's definitely one of those useful bits of info that I'm always happy I stumbled across.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your use-case correctly, I'd avoid calling out to Service A in my integration tests for Service C by mocking the whole Service A with [clj-fake-http](https://github.com/myfreeweb/clj-http-fake). I've used that library very happily in one of my work projects and can highly recommend it.

This assumes that Service A is actually a different process that you're talking to. Should Service A live in the same process as Service C you might as well mock away the calls to the 3rd party API that Service A does.

Comment: While using the API was a minor detail (at least in my head; using a direct database connection instead, for example), I'm loving the referenced library.  I forget things like that exist.

I feel like your second point is coming to a similar conclusion that I came to.  However, if I received nothing more than a jar containing Service A and a bit of documentation, how would I know what underlying functions to mock?  Or, did you mean mock my use of Service A in code that I can directly control?

Comment: My understanding was that you control Service A and would know which calls you make to the 3rd party API. Then, it'd be easy to have a fake HTTP server in your tests of Service C that gives the answers you need. Sorry if I didn't understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use option #2, but `with-redefs`  (there is almost never a need for `with-redefs-fn`.  See

- [the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs).
- The [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

Example:

---

```
(ns http)

(defn post [url] ; dummy fn for testin
  {:body "Hello world"})
```

---

```
(ns app
  (:require [clojure.test :refer [deftest is run-tests]]))

(deftest is-a-macro
  (with-redefs [http/post (fn [url] {:body "Goodbye world"})]
    (is (= {:body "Goodbye world"} (http/post "http://service.com/greet")))))

(run-tests) ;; test is passing
```

Comment: I've used `with-redefs-fn` in other tests, so I do understand how it's used and works (although I hadn't tried `with-redefs`, so thanks for that).  I also updated the question for clarification: I'm trying to write integration tests, and if I don't know the implementation details of Service A, I will not know what to mock at that level.